How to Generate Encryption Keys for Google Pay Direct Integration?
Question:
I am integrating Google Pay into my Android app using the Direct Integration method. On the Google Pay & Wallet Console, it requires me to upload at least one encryption key under the "Encryption Keys" section before I can submit my application for production mode. However, I’m unsure where to get these encryption keys or how to generate them correctly.
What I’ve tried so far:

OpenSSL:

Generated private and public keys using the prime256v1 curve.
Verified the public key output starts with 0x04 (uncompressed format) by extracting it with the following commands:
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out private_key.pem
openssl ec -in private_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.pem
openssl ec -pubin -in public_key.pem -text -noout


Extracted the binary uncompressed public key:
openssl ec -pubin -in public_key.pem -outform DER | tail -c +28 > uncompressed_key.bin


Converted the key to Base64:
openssl base64 -in uncompressed_key.bin -out uncompressed_key_base64.txt



Despite this, the key was rejected by the Google Pay console, with an error saying: "The first byte of the public key must be 0x04 (uncompressed point format)".

PowerShell and Ubuntu:

Followed the same steps using PowerShell on Windows and OpenSSL on Ubuntu, but encountered similar issues.
Checked the decoded binary files and ensured the key format followed ECC P-256 uncompressed specifications, but the Google Pay console still rejected the keys.


JKS Consideration:

Explored whether the required key might be related to the JKS file used for signing the Android app (key alias and password), but this doesn’t seem to align with the documentation.



I’m unclear if I’m generating the correct type of key or if there’s an alternate process to get the encryption key specifically for the Google Pay API.
Could someone clarify:

How to generate this encryption key properly?
What tool or process should be used to ensure compatibility with Google Pay?
Is there documentation or a standard tool used by others who have successfully completed this integration?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!


Figured it out, has to be done on a Mac
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out private_key.pem
openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -text -noout 2> /dev/null | grep "pub:" -A5 | sed 1d | xxd -r -p | base64 | paste -sd "\0" - | tr -d '\n\r ' > publicKey.txt

